# Can I use MEF to create an extensible factory?

Tags: mef

Let me start by saying that I am coming at this with limited MEF experience and have accomplished my goals using both Castle and Unity previously. I'm hoping something similar can be done with MEF.

In short, what I need is a factory class that can instantiate objects by name.  More specifically, I will have an abstract base class such as:

```
public abstract class TheBaseClass { ... }
```

There will be any number of subclasses that derive from the base class:

```
public class OneSubClass : TheBaseClass { ... }

public class AnotherSubClass : TheBaseClass { ... }
```

At runtime, I need a factory that I can call, passing a 'key' value, to get the specific subclass instance returned like:

```
var key = "AnotherSubClass";
TheBaseClass instance = TheFactory.CreateInstance(key);
```

In Castle and Unity, I could register the type with 'key' as the name and use this value as a lookup when trying to resolve the instance from the container.  I thought I might be able to accomplish the same thing using ExportMetadata but am at a stand-still how I can do it.

The rationale behind this approach (in case there's a better way), is that I need to instantiate a strongly-typed subclass at runtime without any knowledge of that type at compile time because the application is extensible and (exported) types can be added through external assemblies.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest to use strongly typed names to avoid mistyping errors.

To do so, first you need to create an enum that you will use as a key:

```
public enum DerivedClassesKeyEnum
{
    ONE,
    TWO
}
```

Then you create a custom attribute:

```
[MetadataAttribute]
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Class)]
public class DirivedBaseExportAttribute : ExportAttribute
{
    public DirivedBaseExportAttribute()
        :base(typeof(TheBaseClass))
    { }

    public DerivedClassesKeyEnum DerivedClassId { get; set; }
}
```

Next, you apply this attribute to yuor derived classes:

```
[DirivedBaseExport(DerivedClassId=DerivedClassesKeyEnum.ONE)]
public class OneSubClass : TheBaseClass
{

}
```

In the part that will import these classes you declare an interface:

```
public interface IDerivedClassMetadata
{
    DerivedClassesKeyEnum DerivedClassId{get;}
}
```

And last bit, in your FactoryClass:

```
public class TheFactory
{
    [ImportMany]
    public static IEnumerable<Lazy<TheBaseClass, IDerivedClassMetadata>> DerivedClasses { get; set; }

    public static TheBaseClass CreateInstance(DerivedClassesKeyEnum id)
    {
        return DerivedClasses.Single(c => c.Metadata.DerivedClassId == id).Value;
    }

}
```

It is simplified code just to illustrate the usage.

Comment: While I appreciate the value of the enum to eliminate "magic strings" having the enum breaks the loosely-coupled (extensible) model because I have to add a new field to the enum each time I want to extend the factory rather than simply dropping the assembly into the runtime directory and allowing discovery to populate the enumerable. Other than that, your solution works perfectly for me. Thx!

Answer (score 2):

this works the same way in MEF as it does in the other IoC containers you mentioned.

```
[Export("one", typeof(TheBaseClass)]
public class OneSubClass : TheBaseClass { ... }

[Export("two", typeof(TheBaseClass)]
public class AnotherSubClass : TheBaseClass { ... }
```

The 'keys' I've assigned here are `"one"` and `"two"` but of course you can use anything you like.

Then, you use that key in combination with `GetExport()`:

```
var catalog = new TypeCatalog(typeof(OneSubClass), typeof(AnotherSubClass));
var container = new CompositionContainer(catalog);

var two = container.GetExport<TheBaseClass>("two");
var value = two.Value;
```

A couple of notes; don't forget to release the exports you get from the container in this way, using for example `container.ReleaseExport(two)`.

You should also note that you can use this with any catalog - I've just chosen `TypeCatalog` for the example, but others work equally well.

Comment: I prefer Slava's solution because I try to avoid referencing the container outside of my initialization code. That said, using the ContractName property on the ExportAttribute is certainly a viable option to all of the work requred to use Metadata - as long as we are only concerned with passing a single string value. Thanks for the response.